# Tooltip control doesn't appear but is created

Tags: c, winapi

I am attempting to get a tooltip to appear over a Static control. I've followed the MSDN example almost word for word but the tooltip doesn't appear. Maybe I need to initialise a specific common control prior to creating a tooltip? Right now I initialise `ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES` and `ICC_COOL_CLASSES`.

Any idea why the tooltip doesn't appear?

```
case WM_CREATE:
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX iccx;
    iccx.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    iccx.dwICC = ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES | ICC_COOL_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&iccx);

    HWND hwndTool = CreateWindowEx(0, _T("Static"), _T("Abc"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
        10, 10, 100, 100, hWnd, (HMENU)50001, hInst, NULL);

    HWND hwndTip = CreateWindowEx(NULL, TOOLTIPS_CLASS, NULL,
        WS_POPUP | TTS_ALWAYSTIP | TTS_BALLOON,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        hWnd, NULL,
        hInst, NULL);

    // Associate the tooltip with the tool.
    LPTSTR pszText = _T("Def");
    TOOLINFO toolInfo = { 0 };
    toolInfo.cbSize = sizeof(toolInfo);
    toolInfo.hwnd = hWnd;
    toolInfo.uFlags = TTF_IDISHWND | TTF_SUBCLASS;
    toolInfo.uId = (UINT_PTR)hwndTool;
    toolInfo.lpszText = pszText;

    output(_T("Is null: %d\n"), hwndTip == NULL); // output = Is null: 0
    output(_T("Send res: %d\n"), SendMessage(hwndTip, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM)&toolInfo)); // output = Send res: 0
}
break;
```

Comment: Tooltips start out inactive, use `TTM_ACTIVATE` to activate them.

Comment: Does adding the WS_EX_TOPMOST extended style to dwExStyle of CreateWindowEx() make a difference?